# В чем разница между Microsoft.Data.SqlClient и Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Я хочу использовать базу данных в веб-приложении на `asp.net core c#`. Не могу понять в чем разница между `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` и `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` и есть ли она?

Что лучше использовать для веб-приложений и почему?

Comment: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - это ADO.NET, низкоуровневый компонент управления базой, где вы за многое отвечаете сами, включая написание запросов к базе. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` - это Entity Framework (EF), уже полноценный компонент, некая обертка над ADO.NET, который многое делает за вас, вам достаточно раз настроить, а дальше использовать что-то по типу `var result = db.Users.Where(x=>x.Age > 20);`, EF сам преобразует это в SQL запрос, сам создаст подключение, отправит, и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это практически одно и то же. Просто `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` позволяет работать в рамках проекта EFC

То есть, грубо говоря, это `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` это надстройка над `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, которая является надстройкой над `System.Data.SqlClient`

Использовать ту или иную идею нужно отталкиваясь от реализации. Приведу пример

1. Вся ваша логика реализуется в базе данных в хранимых процедурах? Лучше используйте `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`
2. Вы хотите, чтобы вся работа с БД была в вашем `C#` проекте и логична для программистов? Лучше используйте `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

[Подробнее об EFC](https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/)

Comment: Спасибо, вполне понятно. Просто видел что с `MS SQL` работают через `SqlClient` и `EFC` , а при работе с `ASP.NET core` используют чаще `EFC`.